Bookmarklet for avoiding logging on Google's sponsored results
I want code for a bookmarklet I can have in my bookmarks bar to avoid the logging on Google's sponsored results.

Tested on Google’s desktop site (as opposed to mobile) in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. It will break if Google renames its sVXRqc class.
javascript: (function () {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('a.sVXRqc');
    links.forEach(function (link) {
        const originalUrl = link.getAttribute('href');
        const newLink = document.createElement('a');
        newLink.href = originalUrl;
        newLink.textContent = 'Original Link ';
        link.parentNode.insertBefore(newLink, link);
    });
})();

